# Changing global variabele reference inside a function php

Tags: php, scope, reference, global-variables

I'm running into an issue with changing a global variable to another reference inside a function.

```
$one = 1;
$two = 2;
$ref = &$one;

change();
echo $ref;

function change(){
    global $ref, $two;
    $ref = &$two;
}
```

The result of the code is "1". I don't really understand why, I would have guessed changing the global variable inside the function it would be persistent after leaving the function scope?

What would be a good workaround (apart from using the GLOBALS array)?

Comment: Try `$ref = $two;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that was a great question. In order to have references returned from functions, use the `&` before the function name as below.

```
$one = 1;
$two = 2;
$ref = &$one;

$ref = &change();
echo $ref;
$two = 3;
echo $ref;

function &change(){
    global $two;
    return $two;
}
```

Output:

```
23
```

Comment: In the end we went for a different solution and used a file-include instead of a function as a workaround. Not a very neat solution, but in the case we had it was better than to use a return value (reference) and change the variable outside the function.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, reference is NOT pointer. It is something like alias of another variable. I will explain what happen with your code:

```
$one = 1;
$two = 2;
$ref = &$one;
```

After three commands above, we have:

```
variables   | $one | $ref | $two |
content     |    1        | 2    |
```

As you see, `$one` and `$ref` refer to *the same* content, it is what the term `reference` meaning. Continue:

```
global $ref, $two;
```

According to [this document](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.spot.php), above command the same as:

```
$ref =& $GLOBALS['ref'];
$two =& $GLOBALS['two'];
```

So, we have:

```
variables   | $one (global) | $ref(global) | $ref (local) | $two (global) | $two (local) |
content     |                    1                        |               2              |
```

Yes, we have 5 variables! Continue:

```
$ref = &$two;
```

It is actually:

```
$ref (local) = &$two (local);
```

So we have:

```
variables   | $one (global) | $ref(global) | $ref (local) | $two (global) | $two (local) |
content     |                    1         |                        2                    |
```

And, the last command:

```
echo $ref;
```

Actually is:

```
echo $ref (global);
```

And, `1` is the correct value!

Additional:

```
change();
echo $two;

function change(){
    global $ref, $two;
    $ref = &$two;
    $ref = 9;
}
```

The result of this code is `9`;

----- EDIT -----

I did not read the question carefully. My answer is for the part `The result of the code is "1". I don't really understand why`. The answer of Jonathan Gagne is what you are looking for.

Comment: You did not make it bro. The echo output `9` only because you assign it inside the function. He just has to use `&` before the function name. If he changes the value of his variable `$two` it is not referencing to the `$ref` variable. Look my solution please you will understand what he was asking for.

Comment: I edited my answer. I did not read the question carefully. But, is there any wrong with my answer?

Comment: Related to his question, If you put `$one = 1; $two = 2; $ref = &$one; echo $ref; change(); echo $ref; $two = 3; echo $ref;` it will output `199` instead `193` as he wants. However, your answer was really instructive and descriptive of the PHP global variable. But did not represent a solution for this question. Thanks for all btw!